# android.support.v4.app.getFragmentManager() returns null?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

This is my Stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.test.fragments.LoadingFragment$1.run(LoadingFragment.java:66)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 66 of my Fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
```

fm is gotten like this:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

My Fragment extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, these are my imports:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

i never had seen that i got null for a FragmentManager anybody got an Idea?

Comment: Can you post your imports section? Are you using the correct lib for FragmentTransaction?

Answer (score -9, accepted):

After cleaning and rebuilding my project aswell as restarting my testing device, this worked again somehow.

Comment: Doesn't effect when clean or rebuild but make sure that getFragmentManager() is of Support library..check the imports

Comment: Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This is not solution!

Comment: There's always one guy who always gave same solution for almost all android problems.

Answer (score 82):

Replace this `getFragmentManager()` with this `getSupportFragmentManager()` and also make sure that your activity extends `FragmentActivity`

Comment: I am calling this inside the Fragment. The Method inside the Fragment is still called getFragmentManager, even in the Support version of the Fragment class. The Activity this Fragment sits in is a FragmentActivity.

Comment: @YallaT. call getSupportFragmentManager() not getFragmentManager()

Comment: there is no getSupportFragmentManager() Method in the support Fragment class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html Sure, i could use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() but why is this not working here ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html see this getSupportFragmentManager() is originally defined in FragmentActivity and is not provided in the Fragment.. So you need to get it from the FragmentActivity you can do it like this getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: getFragmentManager() also works but make sure that the import is of support library

Comment: Yeah, everything worked fine, my imports were correct, but somehow i got this error in 2 instances today,despite it working yesterday, but after rebuilding and cleaning my project the error was gone. Don't know why, but thanks for your effort.

Comment: @YallaT. Good to know your issue is fixed...You are always welcome friend

Comment: I second Yalla T. question. Why does it not work? why should one replace this method with getSupportFragmentManager?

Comment: @Pragnani this is age old but in case you're reading: is there any logical explanation to your solution (why it works)?

Answer (score 4):

From `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` source:

```
// The fragment manager we are associated with.  Set as soon as the
// fragment is used in a transaction; cleared after it has been removed
// from all transactions.
FragmentManagerImpl mFragmentManager;
```

Apparently `getFragmentManager()` returns support version of fragment manager but only during a transaction (or parent fragment's child fragment manager).

I'm going to use this:

```
public FragmentManager getHostFragmentManager() {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm == null && isAdded()) {
        fm = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();
    }
    return fm;
}
```

Comment: so we can assume the fragment is not added?

Comment: what is "isAdded()" .. where is the code of isAdded ?

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra `isAdded()` is method of `Fragment`. I suppose you could use `getActivity() != null` instead.

Answer (score 0):

CASE: When you need to call Fragment(Child fragment) from another Fragment(Parent Fragment)

always use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` inside your Parent Fragment.