# Access method from one fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my Details Fragment. Here I create a public method which will show the clicked item form the listview Fragment which I have described below.

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView text,vers;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailsfragment, container, false);
        text= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.AndroidOs);
        vers= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Version);
        return view;
    }
    public void change(String txt, String txt1){
        text.setText(txt);
        vers.setText(txt1);
    }
}
```

I am trying to set value to Change (xx,xx) method from this ListFragment Activity:

```
public class ListMenuFragment extends ListFragment {

    String[] AndroidOS = new String[] { "Cupcake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo",
            "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb", "Ice Cream SandWich", "Jelly Bean",
            "KitKat" };
    String[] Version = new String[] { "1.5", "1.6", "2.0-2.1", "2.2", "2.3",
            "3.0-3.2", "4.0", "4.1-4.3", "4.4" };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfragment, container, false);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AndroidOS);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        DetailsFragment txt = (DetailsFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.list);
        txt.change(AndroidOS[position], "Version : " + Version[position]);
        getListView().setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
    }

}
```

The List is showing well. But when clicking the list, it's force closing and giving Null Pointer Exception:

```
here : txt.change(AndroidOS[position], "Version : " + Version[position]);
```

And the main activity XML is:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context="com.example.androidlistfragment.MainActivity">
        <fragment
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="240px"
            class="com.example.androidlistfragment.ListMenuFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"/>
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="240px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.example.androidlistfragment.DetailsFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Log cat:

```
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at com.example.androidlistfragment.ListMenuFragment.onListItemClick(ListMenuFragment.java:38)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:160)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1394)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3024)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3830)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
07-24 17:28:22.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22421):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your Activity code..how you are adding fragments???

Comment: What's the output of `Log.d("someTag", " "+txt);` in `onListItemClick`, before NPE? Also, include logcat.

Comment: I tried to set fixed text  txt.change("xx", "dd"); but no luck

Comment: @NRahman if you want our help, please provide enough information. 99 times out of 100 solution is clearly written in Logcat.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uhh... your fragment is null, because you are giving wrong Id. This is Id you give your fragment: `fragment2` and this is Id of fragment you are looking for: `android.R.id.list`.

Comment: Can you be spacific what to do and where'

Comment: No, that's more that's more than enough information. I guess I should have excluded Id's from answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you take look into android developer webpage if not please take a look [HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

In shortcut create interface in fragment implement it in container (activity) set reference and call method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()`, if you are using support library.

Comment: How would that cause NPE?

Comment: Based on this answer and its comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14934697/419308